# 'Ignoring exception in on_message' discord.py ignoring if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I have this code in my discord bot using discord.py

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.author not in config.sections() and message.content == '!!acc': #it seems to ignore this if statement and simply tries executing the code below
            config.add_section(str(message.author))
            config.set(str(message.author), 'Enemy', '10')
            config.set(str(message.author), 'Money', '0')
            config.set(str(message.author), 'Damage', '1')
            config.set(str(message.author), 'Level', '1')
            response = "Your Profile has been created, these are your stats: \nCurrent money: 0 \nCurrent Damage: 1 \nCurrent level: 1"
        
    elif message.content == '!!acc': #this is getting completely ignored too
        response = "Current money: "+str(config.get(message.author, 'Money'))+ "\nCurrent Damage " +str(config.get(message.author, 'Damage'))+ "\nCurrent level: "+str(config.get(message.author, 'Level'))
```

but whenever i type the command !!acc while already heaving an entry in the config i get the following error

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\coding\bot\gamebot.py", line 29, in on_message
    config.add_section(str(message.author))
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\configparser.py", line 1212, in add_section
    super().add_section(section)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\configparser.py", line 659, in add_section
    raise DuplicateSectionError(section)
configparser.DuplicateSectionError: Section 'discord-name' already exists
```

Comment: You say `message.author`, but then you say `str(message.author)`. Is this intentional?

Comment: It doesn't change anything about the functionality but i don't really know myself why i did it.

Comment: You're checking if an `int` is in the config field, and then you set the `str`. That condition will *always evaluate true*.

Comment: Shouldn't message.author and config.sections both be strings by default?

Comment: Try it and see. What is the output of `config.sections()`? (Also for readability, you should probably put the entire `aac` command into one if block and check for duplicates inside it.)

Comment: I'll try it tomorrow but in another test program it simply outputs all different sections in the config file. The acc command was in one block before, the code i pasted was just another attempt of me trying to fix it.

Comment: Try changing it in line 5 to `str(message.author)`. Sidenote: never use usernames, use their ID which you can get from `message.author.id`.

Comment: Thanks it after changing everything to the same type and not having some with string and some without string it now works as intended. I'll change it to the user id too.